# Grabbing line and previous line from hashset with regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

What I am trying to accomplish is in a hashset that contains the following:

```
MSI (c) (AC:C0) [14:23:21:685]: Back from server. Return value: 1603
MSI (c) (AC:C0) [14:23:21:685]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (AC:C0) [14:23:21:685]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its current value is '1'.
Action ended 14:23:21: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (AC:C0) [14:23:21:685]: Doing action: SetupCompleteError
Action 14:23:21: SetupCompleteError. 
Action start 14:23:21: SetupCompleteError.
```

When Return Value 3. is found; the line & the line before it should be added to a second hashset.

```
MSI (c) (AC:C0) [14:23:21:685]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its current value is '1'.
Action ended 14:23:21: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.)
```

This works as the Regex to find that line and the line above (as far as I know) but so far everything i've tried to move both lines to the next hashset only moves the line containing Return value 3.

```
    Dim regrv3 As New Regex("(.*)\S\s(.*)Return value 3.")
```

Relevant code:

```
Dim opened As New HashSet(Of String)(File.ReadAllLines(openfile))
Dim compa As HashSet(Of String) = New HashSet(Of String)

For Each StringMatch In opened
    Dim m As Match
    m = regrv3.Match(StringMatch)
    compa.Add(m.ToString
Next
```

Am I missing something obvious or do I need some sort of complex indexing to perform this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a `HashSet`? If you're simply iterating through it anyway, I don't think you're going to get any benefit from using that data-structure. And any reason you're using a regex? If you're using a list, you can simply iterate through the lines, use `.Contains()` to find the line with "Return value 3" and grab the previous line. Bam! Done!

Comment: @JeffBridgman There are other regex being compared against the hashset and originally I was also using .exceptwith to compare against another hashset. I don't mind using something aside from regex in this particular instance but I should stick with the hashset for comparison

Comment: So if you select the previous line, should that become a single `String` entry in the `HashSet` it gets added to? I don't think order is guaranteed when iterating over a `HashSet` so I think once you've split the file into lines and put it in a `HashSet` there's no way to find the line above anymore... if you can find a regex that'll work I think you'll need to run it on the entire text of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't heard back from you yet, so I'm assuming the line with "Return value 3" and the previous line should be treated as one entry in the hashset. This solution doesn't use regexes, but this should accomplish your goal and still produce an hashset result.

```
Dim inputLines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath)
Dim matches As New HashSet(Of String)

For i = 0 To inputLines.Length - 1
  If inputLines(i).Contains("Return value 3.")
    'Okay we found what we're looking for, combine with previous line
    'Btw... there's an exception hidden here (hint: when i=0)
    Dim match = inputLines(i - 1) & inputLines(i)
    matches.Add(match)
  EndIf
Next
```